# Create UIButton inside struct

Tags: swift

### Situation

Hi! I have the following structure (`struct Product`) for my products and the following function to add a UIButton for each product (`func createButton(...)`)

```
//struct.swift
struct Product {
  var name: String
  var price: Double
  var xPos: Double
  var yPos: Double
  var buttonWidth: Double
  var buttonHeight: Double
}

//ViewController.swift, 
func createButton(product: Product, gridWidth: Double,gridHeight: Double ) {
    let xPos: Double = product.xPos * gridWidth
    let yPos: Double = product.yPos * gridHeight
    let buttonWidth: Double = product.buttonWidth * gridWidth
    let buttonHeight: Double = product.buttonHeight * gridHeight

    let button = UIButton(frame: CGRect(x: xPos, y: yPos, width: buttonWidth, height: buttonHeight))
    button.addTarget(self, action: #selector(buttonAction), for: .touchUpInside)

    viewProducts.addSubview(button)
}

for product in products {
  createButton(product: product, gridWidth: gridWidth, gridHeight: gridHeight)
}
```

### Question

**Now, when I click on a button, I need to retrieve the product instance so I can add it to an `order`. Should I do something like that, and my button will be created with the product? I tried but without success.**

```
struct Product {
  //[ same a before here ]
  button: UIButton
}
```

PS: very new to Swift ;-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A better approach here is to subclass `UIButton` so button will hold a product as follow:

```
class ProductButton : UIButton{

    let product : Product

    init(frame: CGRect, product : Product) {
        self.product = product
        super.init(frame: frame)
    }

    required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        fatalError("init(coder:) has not been implemented")
    }

}
```

Then instead of `UIButton` you will need to create a `ProductButton` and get the product in button's action function

```
func createButton(product: Product, gridWidth: Double,gridHeight: Double ) {
    let xPos: Double = product.xPos * gridWidth
    let yPos: Double = product.yPos * gridHeight
    let buttonWidth: Double = product.buttonWidth * gridWidth
    let buttonHeight: Double = product.buttonHeight * gridHeight

    let button = ProductButton(frame: CGRect(x: xPos, y: yPos, width: buttonWidth, height: buttonHeight), product : product)
    button.addTarget(self, action: #selector(buttonAction(button:)), for: .touchUpInside)

    viewProducts.addSubview(button)
}

func buttonAction(button : ProductButton){
    // Get product here...
    let product = button.product
}
```